# Visual Studio Debug and variable watching

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a really annoying issue with visual studio 2012.
During Debug I was used to look at the results of objects setting breakpoints and then moving mouse over the object and start exploring.

Now on my laptop that has a screen width of 1280px, it's not possible because the variable values are not wrapped, and the box goes completely out of the screen.
see the picture below:

[image: Visual Studio Screen Capture]

and I'm not able anymore to click on the plus sign on the far left to view all the elements of the IEnumerable, or List...etc..

Is there some settings I have to modify to make it work also on 1280px screen?

Comment: A workaround (Until someones find a real solution) would be to right-click the element and select "Add Watch". The element will be placed in the "Watch 1" window at the bottom of the screen, which won't go offscreen. Or "Quick Watch" if you only want to look at it temporarily.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I'm already working this way, but it's frustrating!

Comment: for small screens better thant add watch sometimes is quick watch, but it depends what u prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the root level, it (a DataTip dialog) has an unpin icon. Click the icon and the dialog floats above any open windows, and you can drag the dialog to a comfortable place, so you can expand to view all the elements in the IEnumerable (hopefully 1280px is enough).

[View data values in Data Tips in the code editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd.aspx)

1920px (or higher) is a better ***resolution*.**